# How do I remove a color from the GTK scale widget?

Tags: themes, gtk

I have included a link below. I am making changes to the Ubuntu to rid myself of the all the orange, but it sticks around like the herp. Anyone have any experience with this?

You will notice the string of orange running in the scale widget.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some colors are defined in css style files. Like the one you mention of Scale Widget.

This for Ambiance theme, it's in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`. Here is an example, I have changed it into other color.

```
.scale.trough.highlight {
    /*background-color: #df784e;*/
    background-color: #02FF00;
    background-image: none;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

[image]